# GameLogic, x in a row game

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm making a game and I need to make a method which checks if the specified cell is part of a horizontal consecutive sequence of cells containing the same character. The sequence of cells needs to be of length l. It is true if the cell is part of a horizontal sequence of length at least l, and false otherwise.

So far I have it that it detects if there are at least 5 consecutive cells with the same character anywhere in the row of the character specified. Can anyone help?

Comment: Does your code work or not? If it doesn't then what is the problem? Can you give some example inputs to your method that demonstrate the problem with your current code?

Comment: I need the character at a[row][col] ie the current position to be part of that sequence of >= l

Comment: Can you weave that into the question rather than putting it in a comment?

Comment: run your loop from `col-l+1` to `col+l-1`

Comment: @RohitJain: It is not enough, assume `[a,a,b,a,b,a,a]` (looking for (0,3) with l==4), it will yield true though it should have returned false.

Comment: @amit.. I don't understand your example. I'll post my answer, you can comment there.

Comment: It might be interesting to turn each `char[]` into a string and use regular expressions somehow.

Comment: @amit.. No it won't return true for that case. As soon as `b` is encountered, counter is reset to `0`. See my answer. I posted the code.

Comment: @RohitJain: You are correct, I missed the reset to zero part in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply search for both sides using two loops (one per side) and check if the sum of consecutive cells is indeed `l`. Something along the lines of:

```
public static boolean checkPositionRow(char[][] a, int row, int col, int l) {
    int counter = 1; //starting from 1, because for a[row][col] itself
    char charAtPosition = a[row][col];
   //expand to the right as much as possible
    for (int i = col+1; i < a[row].length && a[row][i] == charAtPosition; i++) counter++;
   //expand to the left as much as possible
    for (int i = col-1; i >= 0 && a[row][i] == charAtPosition; i--) counter++;
    return counter >= l;
}
```

Comment: I think you're close, I had something similar with less in the for loop, but it's not working.

Comment: @user1442762: It should return `true` if and only if index (row,col)  is a part of a (contagious) sequence that contains at least `l` elements with the value `a[row][col]`. Isn't it what you are after? Is it failing to do so? (If so can you show me the failing test case - I assume it is an off by one or other minor bug)

Comment: @user1442762: I tested this sample and it returns `false` for `l > 1`. Note that the last line is `return counter >= l` (small case L), and not 1 (one) - this small typo could explain the behavior you are showing.

Comment: Sorry for making it look like you gave false code, it looked right in my head, and translated on my computer does just as I wanted after i removed some old code, can't thank you enough, you're my accepted answer :)

Comment: Could you use 4 loops to do diagonals?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the column you want to include is - `5`. And length of sequence is `3`.

Now, here are the possibilities of the occurence of your sequence in that row: -

- `Col = (5 - 2) to 5`
- `Col = 5 to (5 + 2)`
- Or, anywhere in between the range [`(5 - 2), (5 + 2)`]

So, the range you are interested in is: - `[col - length + 1, col + length - 1]`. In this range, every sequence of length `3` will include your column `5`.

So, simply run the loop between these range. Now, the problem will be when those range goes out of range. So, you can do that check before.

A better way would be to use `Math.max(0, col-length+1)`, and `Math.min(col + length-1, arraylength)`.

So, you can use this `for-loop`: -

```
public static boolean checkPositionRow(char[][] a, int row, int col, int l) {

  int counter = 0;
  int left = col - l + 1;
  int right = col + l - 1;
  char charAtPosition = a[row][col];

  for (int i = Math.max(0, left); i < Math.min(right, a[row].length); i++) {
        if (a[row][i] == charAtPosition) {
            counter++;
            if (counter >= l)
                return true;

        } else {
            counter = 0;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for your input, explains quite well :)