# Java: checkPositionRow

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GameLogic, x in a row game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692902/gamelogic-x-in-a-row-game)

Description of checkPositionRow:

****checkPositionRow
public static boolean checkPositionRow(char[][] a,
                                       int row,
                                       int col,
                                       int l)
    Checks if the specified cell is part of a horizontal consecutive sequence of cell containing the same character. The sequence of cells needs to be of length l.

Parameters:

- `a` - a 2-dimensional rectangular array of type char.
- `row` - the row the cell in question
- `col` - the column the cell in question
- `l` - the required length of the sequence
  Returns:
  true - if the cell is part of a horizontal sequence of length at least l; false - otherwise.****

Can't get this game to work, need game to return true if they're 5 or more in a row. Here's my attempt (which doesn't work, just returns true all the time, but i need it to return false when the sequence is less than 5):

```
public static boolean checkPositionRow(char[][] a, int row, int col, int l){
  int counter = 1;

  for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    if(a[row][i] == a[row][i+1]) {
      counter++;

      if(counter >= 5){
        return true;
      }                  
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Help!

Comment: Are you making a match-5 game? Theres probably easier ways of doing this.

Comment: @amit Good spot. Looks like a college class has been given an assignment :-)

Comment: @DuncanJones: The method's name: `checkPositionRow()` name looked very familiar...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a[row][i] == a[row][i+1]){
    ...
}else{
  //reset counter
  counter = 1;
}
```

should `i<a.length` need to be `i<a.length -1` else `a[row][i+1]` can give out of bound exception. `a[row].length` for the correct length

```
if(counter >= l){
  //l = required length
  return true;
}
```

rewrite for to while

```
public static boolean checkPositionRow(char[][] grid, int row, int col, int requiredLength) {
  int counter = 0;
  int index = 0;
  char[] charRow = grid[row];
  char charToLookFor = grid[row][col];
  while (index < charRow.length && counter < requiredLength) {
    if (charToLookFor == charRow[index]) {
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter = 0;
    }
    index++;
  }
  return counter == requiredLength;
}
```

you can check if length row greater or equals required length

```
  public static boolean checkPositionRow(char[][] grid, int row, int col, int requiredLength) {
    int counter = 0;
    char[] charRow = grid[row];
    if (charRow.length >= requiredLength) {
      int index = 0;
      char charToLookFor = grid[row][col];
      while (index < charRow.length && counter < requiredLength) {
        if (charToLookFor == charRow[index]) {
          counter++;
        } else {
          counter = 0;
        }
        index++;
      }
    }
    return counter == requiredLength;
  }
```

Comment: This will not provide the correct answer, what if you are looking for position `(0,4)`, with `l==3` in the array `[X,X,X,0,X]`. Note that the suggested solution will yield uncorrectly `true`. There are two correct solutions described in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692902/gamelogic-x-in-a-row-game)

Comment: first parts shows some problems in code from question